# PGFPlots: Drawing a sphere and mapping CIELab color space

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I'm currently working on a figure including a sphere with PGFPlots, based on this (hopefully usable) [Solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124916/draw-sphere-pgfplots-with-axis-at-center), though with a different (kind of exotic) color mapping.

My idea: Applying a mapping and cross-sectioning without lines like the [CIELab Color Space](https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F260118944%2Ffigure%2Ffig22%2FAS%3A667191561166868%401536082272628%2FThe-CIE-Lab-color-dimensionality-The-dimensionality-of-CIE-Lab-color-model-is.png&sp=20959d3e30cc7b77dce9d55f5afb3bc9&anticache=899031), but I am lacking the experience with color mapping (and `\addplot3`) in PGFPlots to solve this issue.

Does anyone have a good guide or tips for color mapping in PGFPlots / TikZ which might help solving this?

I already searched through the [PGFPlots Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=192) (page 192), with

```
colormap={<name>}{<color specification>}
```

stating that one can use [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249164/specifying-which-user-defined-colormap-to-use-in-pgfplots)

```
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={mygreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,0); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,0)}
}
```

to define a color value for a certain axis / at a certain axis value (I guess?).

The special problem now is to get a mapping which is, like in CIELab, axis specific (green / red, blue / yellow, black / white); I just, unfortunately, have no idea how to perform this mapping (and if this is possible at all).

Any ideas out there? :)

Thanks a lot!

Best,

Marius.

Comment: Hey,

oops - sorry! 

Well, the CIELab Color Space describes a sphere in 3D space, having different colors on the x-axis (running from pure green, which would be for example 0,255,0 in RGB, to pure red), y-axis (pure blue to pure yellow) and z-axis (pure white to pure black). 

As far as I understood, PGFPlots can only map a color spectrum to one axis / axis values (in ``\addplot3`` being the z-axis, I think?) and not to three axes, which I would require and which seems to be a little bit more complex; that's at least (apparently) what pops out from the compiling process when using the

Comment: solution I found before.

If you need an image of the color space, I added a link to a figure in the original post. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to answer the question whether or not one can have multidimensional color maps. The answer is yes. There is a specific example on p. 149 of the pgfplots manual, which I am combining with the example you link to. You can let the RGB value of the color depend on the coordinates. I chose `red=y,green=x,blue=z` since I was not really able to parse your description.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        ticks=none,
        enlargelimits=0.3,
        z buffer=sort,
        view/h=45,
        scale uniformly strategy=units only]
% this example burns colors if opacity 
% is active in the document.
    \addplot3 [patch,
        patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:360,
        y domain = 0:180,
        point meta={symbolic={0.5+0.5*y, % R 
            0.5+0.5*x, % G 
            0.5+0.5*z%B
            } },
    ] ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
  \draw (1,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) (0,-1,0)   -- (0,-1.5,0) (0,0,1)   -- (0,0,1.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to see the y dependence, let's change the view

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        ticks=none,
        enlargelimits=0.3,
        z buffer=sort,
        view/h=225,
        scale uniformly strategy=units only]
% this example burns colors if opacity 
% is active in the document.
    \addplot3 [patch,
        patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:360,
        y domain = 0:180,
        point meta={symbolic={0.5+0.5*y, % R 
            0.5+0.5*x, % G 
            0.5+0.5*z%B
            } },
    ] ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
  \draw (-1,0,0)    -- (-1.5,0,0) (0,1,0)   -- (0,1.5,0) (0,0,1)    -- (0,0,1.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please not that the restriction to the RGB color model can easily be lifted: in the `xcolor` manual one finds the formulae that allow one to map RGB to, say, `hsb` or `cmyk`. These transformations can be added to the above.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for this prompt and easy answer - I will try and fit my mapping in and see if I can realize what I am thinking about (I already have a pixel-based figure, which I don't want to use, though). I will, anyway, let you know what I am coming up with and what your answer brought me to (I just have some thinks to do at work, which distracts a little bit). :)

Comment: @Marius OK, glad to hear, just curious what made you unaccept this answer.

Comment: I just updated my post with some of the things you proposed and with things I did during the recent days (and, of course, some new issues following). I hope it's not too messed up and I provided enough code to explain myself; let me know if there's any more code, links, information or files (e.g. log) needed! Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Marius Sorry, this is not the way this site works. If you have a follow-up question, ask a separate question. Asking questions is free of charge. In addition this has the advantage that many users see this and you get more independent opinions and suggestions.

Comment: Ooops, sorry about that; I'm just new to this site, so I'm not aware of this. I reversed the edit and gonna place a new post, referencing this old post / question, then. Thanks for telling me! :)

Comment: @Marius No worries, already upvoted, will look at it later if there is no answer.