# PGFPlots: Mapping CIELab Color Space to a sphere by conversion to RGB color values

Tags: pgfplots, color, conversion, mapping

After already posting a question about [Drawing a sphere and mapping CIELab color space to it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511117/pgfplots-drawing-a-sphere-and-mapping-cielab-color-space) (i.e. generally asking if `pgfplots` allows an axis-dependent color mapping beforehand), I searched all the calculus and theory stuff about CIELab color space I needed, in order to get the equations I need for a (possible) color mapping.

My idea now is to take the `x,y,z` values of my sphere (see MWE below), where, for the CIELab Color Space, I consider my sphere coordinates (all calculated in spherical coordinates incl. `sin` and `cos`) to be `x=a`, `y=b` and `z=L`.

Starting with CIELab Color Space, the calculation should go as follows: `L,a,b --> X,Y,Z --> R,G,B`.

Using this, I first defined necessary functions with [pgfmanual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=1033), p. 1032 / 1033 and

```
declare function = {<function definitions>}
```

plus `ifthenelse` (same package)

```
<statement> ? <yes> : <no>
```

to calculate some coefficients `xr,yr,zr` which are required to perform `L,a,b --> X,Y,Z` as follows:

```
 declare function={% Coefficients xr,yr,zr for X,Y,Z calculation

    xr(\L,\a) = ( (\a/500) + ((\L+16)/116) )^3 > 0.008856 ?%
                ( ((\a/500) + ((\L + 16) / 116))^3 ) :%
                ( 116 * ((\a/500) + ((\L + 16) / 116)) - 16 ) / 903.3;

    yr(\L) = \L > ( 0.008856 * 903.3 ) ?%
             ((\L + 16)/116)^3 :%
             \L / 903.3;

    zr(\L,\b) = ( ((\L + 16) / 116) - (\b/200) )^3 > 0.008856 ?%
                ((((\L + 16) / 116) - (\b/200))^(3)) :%
                ( 116 *  (((\L + 16) / 116) - (\b/200)) - 16 ) / 903.3;
  }
```

Doing this, I acquire the `X,Y,Z` (tristimulus) values by multiplication of those coefficients `xr,yr,zr` with some `illuminant constants Xn,Yn,Zn` to achieve

```
  X = xr(\L,\a) * Xn
  Y = yr(\L)    * Yn
  Z = zr(\L,\b) * Zn
```

Following this, a matrix (matrix elements Mij)

```
       [M11 M12 M13]  -->  gives R value
  M =  [M21 M22 M23]  -->  gives G value
       [M31 M32 M33]  -->  gives B value
```

for `XYZ --> RGB` (both 3x1 vectors) conversion can be used to get the final results (functions `R,G,B`, depending on `\L,\a,\b`):

```
   R(\L,\a,\b) =   xr(\L,\a) * Xn * M11
                 + yr(\L)    * Yn * M12
                 + zr(\L,\b) * Zn * M13;

   G(\L,\a,\b) =   xr(\L,\a) * Xn * M21
                 + yr(\L)    * Yn * M22
                 + zr(\L,\b) * Zn * M23;

   B(\L,\a,\b) =   xr(\L,\a) * Xn * M31
                 + yr(\L)    * Yn * M32
                 + zr(\L,\b) * Zn * M33;
```

Having this, it should (theoretically / as I would think) be possible to simply plug in the coordinates `x=\a` [-100;100], `y=\b` [-100;100] and `z=\L` [0;100] of my sphere to get the results for each `point meta` in `\addplot3`:

```
 \addplot3[point meta = {symbolic = {<R>,<G>,<B>}}] (% Define sphere to be mapped on, incl. limited domains
            {100*cos(azimuth)*sin(polar)},% x
            {100*sin(azimuth)*sin(polar)},% y
            {50*cos(polar)+50}% z
 );
```

Unfortunately, the CIELab model does not exactly represent a sphere (rather an ellipsoid, since the three values of `RGB` (color gamut) can not fill the whole color space of `XYZ` or `Lab` completely, which is also a pretty nasty companion for every company producing colors in TVs, Smartphones etc.), which is why one also has to place exceptions when mapping RGB to a sphere.

Here, I simply defined the `point meta = {symbolic = {<R>,<G>,<B>}}` to replace values `< 0 --> 0` and `> 1 --> 1`, in order to prevent the compiling process from crashing (using nested `ifthenelse`):

```
 point meta={%
   symbolic={%
      % R Values in [0;1]
      ifthenelse( R(z,x,y) < 0 , 0.0 , ifthenelse( R(z,x,y) > 1 , 1.0 , R(z,x,y) ) ),%
      % G Values [0;1]
      ifthenelse( G(z,x,y) < 0 , 0.0 , ifthenelse( G(z,x,y) > 1 , 1.0 , G(z,x,y) ) ),%
      % B Values [0;1]
      ifthenelse( B(z,x,y) < 0 , 0.0 , ifthenelse( B(z,x,y) > 1 , 1.0 , B(z,x,y) ) )%
   }%
 }
```

*And here comes the thing*: It's not compiling successfully, popping errors like `Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point got an ill-formatted floating point number` and even (for some reason) `Unknown function 'Y' in 'xr(1,Y)'` (might be the origin?) which leaves me helpless, since I am lacking the experience to fix it and to exactly know how `pgfplots` processes the data in `mathparse`.

Any ideas how to fix this / make it running successfully?

Here's my **Code*** so far (incl. concrete values plugged in and the commented `mesh/colorspace explicit color input=rgb255`-option, since I, though having the literature, am not sure (yet) whether `R(\L,\a,\b)`, `G(\L,\a,\b)` and `B(\L,\a,\b)` will pop values in [0;1] or [0;255]; I would expect [0;1], though):

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
     \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
       \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

 \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[%
     declare function={%
       % Calculation scheme:   Lab --> XYZ --> RGB [0;1]
       % Math, formulas and values based on
       %  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminant_D65
       %  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space
       %  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RGB_color_space
       %  - http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html
       %  - http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_Lab_to_XYZ.html
       %  - http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html (with XYZ -> sRGB)
       %
       % Declaring Functions to calculate CIE XYZ values --> RGB from the following variables:
       % \L = L-value of CIE Lab space
       % \a = a-value of CIE Lab space
       % \b = b-value of CIE Lab space
       % xr, yr, zr = Coefficients required to get XYZ (from L,a,b)
       %
       % D65 illuminant tristimulus values (T = 6504 K;)
       % Xn = 0.968774;
       % Yn = 1.0;
       % Zn = 1.121774;
       %
       % CIE constants (E = epsilon, K = kappa)
       % E = 0.008856;
       % K = 903.3;
       %
       % XYZ -> sRGB matrix:
       %       [3.2404542 -1.5371385 -0.4985314]   --> R Value
       %   M = [-0.9692660  1.8760108  0.0415560]  --> G Value
       %       [0.0556434 -0.2040259  1.0572252]   --> B Value
       %
       % Coefficients xr,yr,zr for X,Y,Z calculation
       xr(\L,\a) = ( (\a/500) + ((\L+16)/116) )^3 > 0.008856 ?% > E?
                   ( ( (\a/500) + ((\L+16) / 116) )^3 ) :%
                   ( 116 * ((\a/500) + ((\L+16)/116)) - 16 ) / 903.3;
       %
       yr(\L)    = \L > ( 0.008856 * 903.3 ) ?% < (E * K)?
                   ( (\L+16)/116 )^3 :%
                   \L / 903.3;
       %
       zr(\L,\b) = ( ((\L+16)/116) - (\b/200) )^3 > 0.008856 ?% > E?
                   ( ( ((\L+16)/116) - (\b/200) )^3 ) :%
                   ( 116 * (((\L+16)/116) - (\b/200)) - 16 ) / 903.3;%
       % Calculation of R,G,B via illuminant properties and matrix values (XYZ -> sRGB)
       R(\L,\a,\b) = xr(\L,\a) * 0.968774 * 3.2404542 + yr(\L) * 1.0 * (-1.5371385) + zr(\L,\b) * 1.121774 * (-0.4985314); % Including Xn, Yn, Zn, first matrix row
       G(\L,\a,\b) = xr(\L,\a) * 0.968774 * (-0.9692660) + yr(\L) * 1.0 * 1.8760108 + zr(\L,\b) * 1.121774 * 0.0415560;     % Including Xn, Yn, Zn, second matrix row
       B(\L,\a,\b) = xr(\L,\a) * 0.968774 * 0.0556434 + yr(\L) * 1.0 * (-0.2040259) + zr(\L,\b) * 1.121774 * 1.0572252;    % Including Xn, Yn, Zn, third matrix row
     }
   ]
   \begin{axis}[axis equal,
     width = 10cm,
     height = 10cm,
     axis lines = center,
     xmin = -120,
     xmax = 120,
     ymin = -120,
     ymax = 120,
     zmin = 0,
     zmax = 100,
     ticks = none,
     enlargelimits = 0.3,
     z buffer = sort,
     view/h = 45,
     scale uniformly strategy = units only]

     \addplot3 [%
       patch,
       patch type=bilinear,
       variable = \azimuth,
       variable y = \polar,
       domain = 0:360,
       y domain = 0:180,
       fill opacity = 0.5,
       draw opacity = 1,
       line width = 0.001 pt,
       samples = 10, % only for faster compilation
       mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
       % mesh/colorspace explicit color input=rgb255, % if RGB values are calculated in [0 ; 255]
       point meta={%
         symbolic={%
           % R Values [0;1]
           ifthenelse( R(z,x,y) < 0 , 0.0 , ifthenelse( R(z,x,y) > 1 , 1.0 , R(z,x,y) ) ),% check r < 0 and r > 1
           % G Values [0;1]
           ifthenelse( G(z,x,y) < 0 , 0.0 , ifthenelse( G(z,x,y) > 1 , 1.0 , G(z,x,y) ) ),% check g < 0 and g > 1
           % B Values [0;1]
           ifthenelse( B(z,x,y) < 0 , 0.0 , ifthenelse( B(z,x,y) > 1 , 1.0 , B(z,x,y) ) )% check b < 0 and b > 1
         }%
       },
     ] (% Define sphere to be mapped on
          {100*cos(azimuth)*sin(polar)},%  x
          {100*sin(azimuth)*sin(polar)},%  y
          {50*cos(polar)+50}%              z
       );
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your ideas! :)
- Marius.

---

*adapted from `Schrödinger's cat`'s proposal in the [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511117/pgfplots-drawing-a-sphere-and-mapping-cielab-color-space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues which are somewhat (?) non-obvious. I replaced your variables `\L`, `\a` and `\b` by `\u`, `\v` and `\w`. I know it should not make a difference, but according to what I find it did. And then I added braces around the functions (which I also renamed to `myR`, `myG` and `myB` to be on the safer side), and replaced the complicated `ifthenelse` by an arguably less complicated combination of `min` and `max`. Then it worked.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
     declare function={%
       % Calculation scheme:   Lab --> XYZ --> RGB [0;1]
       % Math, formulas and values based on
       %  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminant_D65
       %  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space
       %  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RGB_color_space
       %  - http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html
       %  - http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_Lab_to_XYZ.html
       %  - http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html (with XYZ -> sRGB)
       %
       % Declaring Functions to calculate CIE XYZ values --> RGB from the following variables:
       % \L = L-value of CIE Lab space
       % \a = a-value of CIE Lab space
       % \b = b-value of CIE Lab space
       % xr, yr, zr = Coefficients required to get XYZ (from L,a,b)
       %
       % D65 illuminant tristimulus values (T = 6504 K;)
       % Xn = 0.968774;
       % Yn = 1.0;
       % Zn = 1.121774;
       %
       % CIE constants (E = epsilon, K = kappa)
       % E = 0.008856;
       % K = 903.3;
       %
       % XYZ -> sRGB matrix:
       %       [3.2404542 -1.5371385 -0.4985314]   --> R Value
       %   M = [-0.9692660  1.8760108  0.0415560]  --> G Value
       %       [0.0556434 -0.2040259  1.0572252]   --> B Value
       %
       % Coefficients xr,yr,zr for X,Y,Z calculation
       xr(\u,\v) = ( (\v/500) + ((\u+16)/116) )^3 > 0.008856 ?% > E?
                   ( ( (\v/500) + ((\u+16) / 116) )^3 ) :%
                   ( 116 * ((\v/500) + ((\u+16)/116)) - 16 ) / 903.3;
       %
       yr(\u)    = \u > ( 0.008856 * 903.3 ) ?% < (E * K)?
                   ( (\u+16)/116 )^3 :%
                   \u / 903.3;
       %
       zr(\u,\w) = ( ((\u+16)/116) - (\w/200) )^3 > 0.008856 ?% > E?
                   ( ( ((\u+16)/116) - (\w/200) )^3 ) :%
                   ( 116 * (((\u+16)/116) - (\w/200)) - 16 ) / 903.3;%
       % Calculation of R,G,B via illuminant properties and matrix values (XYZ -> sRGB)
       myR(\u,\v,\w) = xr(\u,\v) * 0.968774 * 3.2404542 + yr(\u) * 1.0 * (-1.5371385) + zr(\u,\v) * 1.121774 * (-0.4985314); % Including Xn, Yn, Zn, first matrix row
       myG(\u,\v,\w) = xr(\u,\v) * 0.968774 * (-0.9692660) + yr(\u) * 1.0 * 1.8760108 + zr(\u,\v) * 1.121774 * 0.0415560;     % Including Xn, Yn, Zn, second matrix row
       myB(\u,\v,\w) = xr(\u,\v) * 0.968774 * 0.0556434 + yr(\u) * 1.0 * (-0.2040259) + zr(\u,\v) * 1.121774 * 1.0572252;    % Including Xn, Yn, Zn, third matrix row
     }
   ]
   \begin{axis}[axis equal,
     width = 10cm,
     height = 10cm,
     axis lines = center,
     xmin = -120,
     xmax = 120,
     ymin = -120,
     ymax = 120,
     zmin = 0,
     zmax = 100,
     ticks = none,
     enlargelimits = 0.3,
     z buffer = sort,
     view/h = 45,
     scale uniformly strategy = units only]

     \addplot3 [%
       patch,
       patch type=bilinear,
       variable = \azimuth,
       variable y = \polar,
       domain = 0:360,
       y domain = 0:180,
       fill opacity = 0.5,
       draw opacity = 1,
       line width = 0.001 pt,
       samples = 10, % only for faster compilation
       mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
       % mesh/colorspace explicit color input=rgb255, % if RGB values are calculated in [0 ; 255]
       point meta={%
         symbolic={%
           % R Values [0;1]
           {min(max(myR(z,x,y),0),1)},%min(max(myR(z,x,z),0),1),% check r < 0 and r > 1
           % G Values [0;1]
           {min(max(myG(z,x,y),0),1)},%min(max(myG(z,x,y),0),1),% check g < 0 and g > 1
           % B Values [0;1]
           {min(max(myB(z,x,y),0),1)}%min(max(myB(z,x,y),0),1)% check b < 0 and b > 1
         }%
       },
     ] (% Define sphere to be mapped on
          {100*cos(azimuth)*sin(polar)},%  x
          {100*sin(azimuth)*sin(polar)},%  y
          {50*cos(polar)+50}%              z
       );
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Fixed the typos and wrong variables I introduced. At least I hope I did.

Comment: Nice - it works perfectly! :)

The only thing I had to change was the equations; you apparently placed the parameters a little bit wrong, such that the color space does not show all the colors which it should.

The things I changed are ``myR(\u,\v,\w)``, ``myG(\u,\v,\w)``, ``myB(\u,\v,\w)`` (instead of ``\u,\u,\v``), ``xr(\u,\v)`` (instead of ``\u,\u``), ``zr(\u,\w)`` (instead of ``\u,\v``) and ``myR(z,x,y)`` (instead of ``z,x,z``), which then prints the correct mapping (currently using samples between 30 and 40, which does not need so much compiling time).

Comment: Thank you very much @Schrödinger's cat, I really appreciate it! :)

But just because I'm curious: Do you have any explanation or idea why ``\L`` (= ``\u``), ``\a`` (= ``\v``) and ``\b`` (= ``\w``) did not work? Internal processing methods of ``pgfplots``?

Comment: @Marius Yes, very likely that I messed this up when letting my editor replace things. (I do not know which of `\a`, `\b` and `\L` is the culprit but would assume it is `\L`. It is generally not recommended to play with one-letter uppercase letters for macros, some of them even get redefined by the engine, e.g. `xlatex` uses `\U`. But I really don't know.) I plan to fix the redefinitions when I have more time.

Comment: Aaaah, alright, so pretty unclear stuff going on there, then. But good to know! I will think about your comment next time doing such (or similar) stuff again, then.

Thanks again! And take your time - I will check again after your update, such that other people searching for this (CIELab is a common model used in material sciences, lighting engineering or other fields dealing with coloring / color changes or similar) later will have the correct model and data to work with.

Comment: * Oh, but one last thing I forgot to mention about my changes:

The space is intended to (somewhat) look like a sphere, such that I also changed ``zmax`` from ``100`` to ``120`` and defined the x- and y-coordinate to be scaled with ``50`` (instead of ``100``). Just for a better (or somewhat more appropriate) appearance, even though (in theory) being not completely correct, since (for example) one (``a`` or ``b``, I forgot) is only fitting to a range of about ``85``, while the other runs up to about ``115``. It's somewhere hidden in the web, but a sphere will at least fit to

Comment: most of the models found in the web when searching for "CIELab space" on Google or something. A sphere will, anyway, look nice (at least) and do fine, too. ;)

Comment: If interested: for color (comparison) examples, see e.g. ["Lab Color Space" on (unfortunately only the german) Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab-Farbraum#Umrechnung_von_RGB_zu_Lab) (subsection "Conversion from RGB to Lab").